# В созданном csv файле не появляется текст

Tags: python, парсер, requests, csv, bs4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'https://moscow.e2e4online.ru/catalog/noutbuki-42/?sort=PRICE_DESC'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
model = soup.find_all('a', class_='block-offer-item__name')
configuration = soup.find_all('div', class_='block-offer-item__description lg-and-up')
price = soup.find_all('div', class_='price-block__price _WAIT')
availability = soup.find_all('div', class_='offer-availability-info block-offer-item__reference-availability offer-availability-info_WAIT')
with open('expensive_laptops.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
    for m, c, p, a in zip(model, configuration, price, availability):
        file.write(f'{m.get_text()}|{c.get_text()}|{p.get_text()}|{a.get_text()}')
```

Причём, в файле ничего не появляется

Comment: Список `availability` у вас пустой получается. Почему - разбирайтесь. Другие три списка не пустые. `zip` итерируется до исчерпания самого короткого списка, поэтому цикл ни разу не отрабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

Вся загвоздка в том, что данные о гарантии, дате поступления, накопленных баллах и прочая информация подгружаются другими запросами. Если открыть на вкладке Сеть предварительный просмотр страницы noutbuki-42/, то можно увидеть, что на самом деле попадает в response. Конкретно дата поступления находится в запросе https://moscow.e2e4online.ru/api/graphql?op=OfferAvailabilityInfo_GetOffer. Ответом будет json, распарсив который можно получить дату поступления.